# Pcl object reconstruction

Tags: camera-calibration, point-cloud-library, multiview

I have a square table with four cameras (Xtion pro), one at each angle.
I'm trying to reconstruct the complete point-cloud of an arbitrary object that is on the table.

I've calibrated the cameras. Intrinsic parameters with a chessboard, and estrinsic parameters with a tag like ARToolkit.

The problem is that when I transform the point-clouds from camera's frame to the tag-defined frame I have errors, quite big.

How can I correct this error? I tried registration with ICP with poor results.
How can I use the obtained transformed cloud as initial guess for a fine registration?
Any suggestion is appreciated!

---

Edit after D.J.Duff comment:

I'm using Xtion PRO version without the RGB camera. So I'm calibrating the IR camera. To do so I covered the IR projector and performed the calibration with the IR stream with the ready to use ROS calibration tool for intrinsic parameters and the [PiTag tags](http://www.dsi.unive.it/~bergamasco/papers/mva2012-pitag.pdf) to calibrate extrinsic parameters.

I should manually align the cloud with a known object, but can this be automated? In sense: if I use something like an L-shaped object with no orientation ambiguities, can I automate the registration process to obtain a better transform matrix?

Comment: Some ideas: (1) If you redo the calibration do you get exactly the same error? (would mean it is precise but inaccurate). (2) If it turns out to be imprecise I could suggest adding other calibration techniques, e.g. manually align point clouds for known object. (3) If inaccurate then there is an issue with the calibration. Each xtion has 2 cameras; which one are you calibrating with respect to and does that calibration carry over to the point cloud frame?

Comment: Thank you very much, I updated the question with more information following your ideas!

Comment: I can't help you more with the first part of your edit without doing some research about the specific camera models and frameworks; seems okay; will leave that up to you. Regarding part 2. If you use 3 spheres then you can use PCL's sphere-RANSAC to find them all and then correspondence rejection with matches between the spheres centroids. Saves you having to find a custom object.

Comment: Also, do try recalibrating; if you learn the answer to q.1 then you have more to go on.